# Why do the Sliders insist on constantly "getting involved"?

Tags: sliders

It seems that whenever the Sliders "get involved" on an earth they visit, trouble befalls them. Sometimes, they have no choice: in "The Exodus," for example, it would have been silly for them to sit around and not try to help when the pulsar threatened the world. Same with "End of Days."

But often, just minding their own business would save them much heartache, the loss of the timer, getting threatened by "bad guys," getting into fights, etc.

Obviously, the out-of-universe reason is that there wouldn't be much of a show if all the Sliders did was walk peacefully down the streets, shop at stores and wait quietly until the next slide. But what is the canon reason? I realize that they're explorers and such, but you'd think that after facing death or personal injury for the umpteenth time that they'd be a little less willing to get involved all the time.

Comment: Because it would have been a crappy show if they'd just hid in the corner for 45 minutes and waited until the next slide.

Comment: I suggested that in my post, of course.

Comment: They would have needed to rename the series; http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgzyl.jpg

Comment: That's funny. Though such a premise for the show still would have probably been better than some of the later-season episodes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely a lot of the time they dont get involved there are numerous mentions of worlds we never see where they had a peaceful time (admittedly there are mentions of not so peaceful times we never saw as well) there are also numerous instances of them exiting the wormhole in a very good mood which lend credence to the theory.

There is also the fact that in a lot of situations the involvement was accidental, one of their doubles being a notorious criminal of one sort or another (the episode where Q picks up a wallet and the drug use enforcement episode), they do something without realizing the consequences (the lottery episode, the episode where Wade kisses the infected individual)